# Deny Access to all directory and file listing with .htaccess

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

What is the code used in `.htaccess` to prevent access of other files in my public folder ( LARAVEL project under shared hosting )?

I have a file called `index.php` and I want this file to be the only file able to access all the other files/directories.

I have seen other solutions here on StackOverFlow but they do not match  above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can block an access to a folder with this code in the `.htaccess`

```
<Directory "/file/">
     deny from all
</Directory>
```

You have to modify the "file" by the name of your files.

But I do not know if that's what you're looking for so you can do this too:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php
```

Comment: no , i want only (index.php) to access all files and directories in the root folder , i can't use your solution because i have a looot of files

Comment: But can you rewrite the URL, with `RewriteEngine on` and `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has it's own .htaccess ready and that should work with your shared hosting too..

```
myfoldersite/public/.htaccess
```

move to

```
myfoldersite/.htaccess
```

and rename

```
myfoldersite/server.php
```

to

```
index.php
```

And try browsing your site again, let's see if that works.

Cheers!